# How to change the width of the row of a UITableView

Tags: iphone

Can we resize the width of the row of a UITableView.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Only if you fit the whole table into a smaller area.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

I'm not 100%, but I am pretty sure each row is going to be with same width as the parent table. However, if you have a custom UITableViewCell, you can make it transparent, and organize your objects on the cell's view to mimic a different sized cell. For example if you wanted a cell to be 50px less wide than the other cells and indented, you could place a white UIView on the transparent cell, make it 50px less wide than it should be, and position it to the right.

Make sense?

Comment: Well Yeah, programatically we can do any thing but I wanted to know if there is some way we can call the delegate to resize it.

Comment: There is no delegate method to control the width of a row. It wouldn't be meaningful, since a UITableView is a stack of rows. The UITableView wouldn't know what to draw in the space that was left over. If you wanted to teach it what to do, you of course can subclass UITableView or possibly UITableViewCell, though I don't believe it's intended to be subclassed this way.

Answer (score 1):

I understand this is an old question, but I need a table cell to be less than the width of the screen, but still be scrollable by touch on either edge, and the cell highlight not to be full width.

I overrode the UITableViewCell setFrame method, like so:

```
- (void) setFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (frame.size.width > 540.0f) {

        frame.origin.x = (frame.size.width-540.0f)/2.0f;
        frame.size.width = 540;
    }
    [super setFrame:frame];
}
```

I guess this is a slightly hacky solution, but it works a treat!

Hope this helps someone.